# SharePoint Online: Setting window changed

Tags: sharepoint-online, settings

Hope you all are well;

Has the settings window changed in SharePoint online?

The layout is different than previous.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it has changed.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**.

Recently In OneDrive and SharePoint, a bold new suite header is released. This is for consistency in look to bring all apps together and to simplify your interaction with the header.

**Reference**:

1. [SharePoint Online Settings menu change?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/SharePoint-Online-Settings-menu-change/m-p/357012?advanced=false&collapse_discussion=true&q=Sharepoint%20online%20settings%20changed&search_type=thread)
2. [New Office 365 Navigation Bar](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-OneDrive-Blog/OneDrive-Message-Center-Updates-January-15th-to-January-31st/ba-p/332041).

Comment: Does this answer helped you in any way to get the relevant information?